# Setting all checkboxes in a listView in another application with winAPI

Tags: c#, listview, winapi, sendmessage

So I have this code to set all items (or even a single item i stated the code for item number 3) for a listview in another application using sendmessage, I already managed to successfully get the item window handle of the listview and got the item count right but when i use setitemstate the other application gives me error and closes (given that there is another application I have that do this job just fine but i don't have its source code)

this is my code :

```
if (windowName.Contains("Invite to Room")) {
    IntPtr hwndChild0 = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", "");

    int itemCount = SendMessage(hwndChild0, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    LV_ITEM lvItem = new LV_ITEM();
    lvItem.Index = 3;
    lvItem.SubIndex = 2;
    lvItem.TextLength = 50;
    lvItem.Mask = LVIF_STATE;
    lvItem.State = LVIS_SELECTED;
    lvItem.StateMask = LVIS_SELECTED;

    SendMessage(hwndChild0, LVM_SETITEMSTATE, 3, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

this is my LV_ITEM structure

```
public struct LV_ITEM
{
    public uint Mask;
    public int Index;
    public int SubIndex;
    public int State;
    public IntPtr StateMask;
    public string Text;
    public int TextLength;
    public int ImageIndex;
    public IntPtr LParam;
}
```

and this is the declaration of the used (sendmessage and setitemstate)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);

private const uint LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
private const uint LVM_SETITEMSTATE = (LVM_FIRST + 43);
```

any help with this?

Edit :

the application error has a log file that said the following message :
"The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it doesn't have the appropriate access"

Comment: well stating that it gives an error and shuts down does nobody any good.. what is the actual error..?

Comment: there is no error it is just not doing the right behavior as it supposed

Comment: Is it givin an error or not? If it gives an error, which one? if no, what is "not doing the right behavior"? please, be more specific.

Comment: @Gusman ok as for debugging no exeption at all, for the other application it gives me that error "Fatal Exception" "Paltalk encountered an error and about to close"

Comment: @Gusman edited it Title: "Fatal Exception" Content: "Paltalk encountered an error and about to close"

Comment: i also accessed the log file of the error it has the following "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it doesn't have the appropriate access"

Comment: You aren't using `LVM_SETITEMSTATE` properly. If you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761196(v=vs.85).aspx), you'd see that passing `-1` to `wParam` would affect all items. You would also see that `lParam` **must** be a pointer to a `LVITEM` structure. You seem to be building one, but just pass `NULL` instead. And even if you did pass a pointer to your `LVITEM`, it still won't work because there's no automatic marshaling for `WM_USER`-range messages, so you must manually write that `LVITEM` directly into the target process's memory. Good luck!

Comment: (This last bit can be deduced from the log message.)

Comment: @andlabs already tried all what you said same error happens "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it doesn't have the appropriate access"

Comment: And when you wrote the `LVITEM` to the target process's memory, did you pass the address of the `LVITEM` in the target process's address space to `SendMessage()`?

Comment: @andlabs yes i did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some messages only use `WPARAM`, `LPARAM` and return `LRESULT` to pass data around, like `LVM_GETITEMCOUNT` that worked for you.

Other messages use pointers to some data structure to be used or filled, like `LVM_SETITEMSTATE`. It expects a pointer to pre-filled `LV_ITEM` structure in `LPARAM`, while you pass `IntPtr.Zero` - so you cause an access violation in that other application trying to dereference that zero pointer.

However, you can't just simply pass the pointer to your `lvItem`, as it wouldn't make any sense in another process. You need to allocate a memory for that structure in the second process, initialize it, send you message and read that memory back (if you expect any response).